# PayPal checkout: Is there documentation for the `actions` parameter of the `createOrder` and `onApprove` functions?

Tags: paypal

In the examples I have seen:

- actions.order.create()
- actions.order.capture()
- actions.redirect()

What else is there? E.g.:

- actions.cancel() ?
- actions.error() ?

Context: I'm trying to figure out how to handle errors from my server during order creation or capture.

Answer (score 0):

The most complete reference you'll find is https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/javascript-sdk/javascript-sdk-reference/ , but some things like actions.redirect are only mentioned elsewhere

As far as handling errors from your server, the best sample for capture errors is https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server , and you can also implement the generic onError function